# How to match HTML "selected" option with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Browsers consider an `<option>` selected by default if it has the `selected="selected"` attributes. But this somehow works even if that attribute value is omitted.

So

`<option selected="selected" value="1">value text</option>`

and this works

`<option selected value="1">value text</option>`

My question is how to write a Regex pattern that matches both conditions above, but never matches something like

`<option value="the devil with **selected** ">value text</option>`

EDIT: I forgot to mention that some conditions are still considered valid XHTML, like selected='selected', or selected=selected or even selected=SelEctEd

Comment: I know that regular expressions are not perfect, if ever useful, to parse XHTML. But in my case there's no way to use other tools like an XML parser

Comment: Sry to say this, but I won't do any thinking before I can see your own try on this that does not work. You know exactly whats supposed to go in what should come out, so I see no reason to do your work. ;)

Comment: I don't think selected=selected is valid XHTML.

Comment: Empty attributes are [quite well standardized](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty), and even recommended for those attributes. In X(HT)ML this [is not allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/#h-4.5) however.

Comment: selected is a property, its just mether is it set or not

Comment: I know this isn't RegEx - but you are using PHP and it's [so simple using DOMDocument so here is some example code](https://3v4l.org/fllP7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions here, and some other resources like "[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?lq=1#answer-1732454)" I realized it's impractical to use Regular expressions to accurately parse XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

With PCRE (which PHP uses) this works:

```
<option.*?\s(?:selected(?:=\"selected\")?)\s.*?>
# look for <option literally
# followed by anything (non greedy) and a whitespace(!)
# open a non capturing group and look for selected, eventually followed by ="selected"
# close the group, followed by a whitespace
# followed by anything (non-greedy) and the closing tag
```

See [a regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ2dR8/2) here. Besides, read the comments, there a good hints (using DomDocument, etc.) in there.

Comment: Unfortunately that matches `<option value=" this is not the selected attribute">value text</option>`

Comment: True. Can you give an overview of your expected input strings then? And **why** exactly is using a decent DOM parser not an option?

Comment: I deal with documents that might have broken or incorrectly formatted tags for an automated test process. It's a complicated scenario. But overall I decided to give up Regexp and go with DomDocument, I did not know it will handle incorrect XHTML that well.  For your other question, I mentioned in the question that all I want is to detect that attribute in any format a typical browser would.